# Use contains to merge data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two separates files, one from our service providers and the other is internal (HR).

The service providers write the names of our employer in different ways, there are those who write it in firstname lastname format, or first letter of the firstname and the last name or lastname firstname...while the HR file includes separately the first and last name.

DF1

```
Full Name
0   B.pitt
1   Mr Nickolson Jacl
2   Johnny, Deep
3   Streep Meryl
```

DF2

```
First   Last
0   Brad    Pitt
1   Jack    Nicklson
2   Johnny  Deep
3   Streep  Meryl
```

My idea is to use str.contains to look for the first letter of the first name and the last name. I've succed to do it with static values using the following code:

```py
    df1[['Full Name']][df1['Full Name'].str.contains('B')
                       & df1['Full Name'].str.contains('pitt')]
```

Which gives the following result:

```
Full Name
0   B.pitt
```

The challenge is comparing the two datasets... Any advise on that please?

Regards

Comment: What is you desired output?

Comment: DataFrame with the columns of the two dataframes.

Comment: Can you please provide the actual dataframe look

Comment: can't DF1 and DF2 help?

Answer (score 0):

if you are just checking if it exists or no this could be useful:
because it is rare to have 2 exactly the same family name, I recommend to just split your Df1 and compare families, then for ensuring you can differ first names too
you can easily do it with a for:

```
for i in range('your index'):
 if df1_splitted[i].str.contain('family you searching for'):
  print("yes")
```

if you need to compare in other aspects just let me know

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use next module for parsing names:

```
pip install nameparser
```

Then you can process your data frames :

```
from nameparser import HumanName
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Full Name':['B.pitt','Mr Nickolson Jack','Johnny, Deep','Streep Meryl']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'First':['Brad', 'Jack','Johnny', 'Streep'],'Last':['Pitt','Nicklson','Deep','Meryl']})

names1 = [HumanName(name) for name in df1['Full Name']]
names2 = [HumanName(str(row[0]+" "+ str(row[1]))) for i,row in df2.iterrows()]
```

After that you can try comparing `HumanName` instances which have parsed fileds. it looks like this:

```
<HumanName : [
    title: '' 
    first: 'Brad' 
    middle: '' 
    last: 'Pitt' 
    suffix: ''
    nickname: '' ]
```

I have used this approach for processing thousands of names and merging them to same names from other documents and results were good.

More about module can be found at https://nameparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Hey you could use fuzzy string matching with [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy)

First create Full Name for `df2`

```
df2_ = df2[['First', 'Last']].agg(lambda a: a[0] + ' ' + a[1], axis=1).rename('Full Name').to_frame()
```

Then merge the two dataframes by index

```
merged_df = df2_.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Now you can apply `fuzz.token_sort_ratio` so you get the similarity

```
merged_df['similarity'] = merged_df[['Full Name_x', 'Full Name_y']].apply(lambda r: fuzz.token_sort_ratio(*r), axis=1)
```

This results in the following dataframe. You can now filter or sort it by similarity.

```
     Full Name_x    Full Name_y        similarity
0    Brad Pitt      B.pitt             80
1    Jack Nicklson  Mr Nickolson Jacl  80
2    Johnny Deep    Johnny, Deep       100
3    Streep Meryl   Streep Meryl       100
```

Comment: That's an excellent solutions, i tested it and it works, but it would take time for me to process it, as i'm new to Python. Thanks for your help

Comment: Feel free to ask more specific questions about the solution if you need help processing it